# Delegating information from view controller within a tab bar controller within a container view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Edited...
My set up for my app is 
View Controller (Contains textView and Container View)
A tab bar Controller was embedded in the container view
With in the tab bar controller are multiple view controllers
I would like to know how delegate information from one of these view controller to the Main View Controller that contains the text view and container view.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is very vague, but you can make a protocol, make the main view controller conform to it, set a property on the child controller, and use that property to call the method in the main view controller.

Comment: Could you specify what kind of information you want to pass around? May notifications would be a clean option.

Comment: I want to get the text from the textview and adjust in another viewcontroller (its font, color, spacing, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not totally clear, rather than using protocol / delegate, you may want to have a look at nsnotificationcenter. For instance create an observer which listens and reacts upon a notification post:

[Apple Documentation for NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html)